# Symfony2.7 form not valid

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.7

I'm developping a blog using Symfony 2.7. I've an ArticleBundle and a CommentBundle. My entities Article and Comment are linked by a ManyToOne relation.

When I try to send a comment, it fails. The $form->isValid() method returns false.

Here, my add method to send a comment :

```
public function addAction(Article $article, Request $request){
    $comment = new Comment();

    $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType(), $comment);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        $comment->setArticle($article);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($comment);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('esgi_article_view', array(
            'id' => $article->getId()
        )));
    } else{
        return $this->render('ESGICommentBundle:Comment:add.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'article' => $article
        ));
    }
}
```

My comment form is inclued into article's view like this :

```
{{ render(controller("ESGICommentBundle:Comment:add", { 'id' : article.id })) }}
```

And here my form :

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
            {{ form_label(form.author, "Auteur") }}
            {{ form_widget(form.author, { 'attr' : { 'class' : 'form-control' } }) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.author) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
            {{ form_label(form.email, "Email (optionnel)") }}
            {{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr' : { 'class' : 'form-control' } }) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
            {{ form_label(form.content, "Commentaire") }}
            {{ form_widget(form.content, { 'attr' : { 'class' : 'form-control' } }) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.content) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Poster</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Thanks, have a nice day !

Comment: Probably you forgot to add action to your form that must be set if you render this form on different url's.

Comment: I tried this before posting but it did not work.

Comment: @L.Baptiste Add `var_dump($form->getErrors(true))` (`dump($form->getErrors(true))` ` in case of DebuggerBundle installed) followed by `die();` after `$form->handleRequest($request);`

Comment: @L.Baptiste `else` part is redundant in your code, you can just return the second return statement outside of `if` statement..

Comment: getErrors returns an empty array.

Comment: @L.Baptiste Look at [the source of](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/51df867c4cfac4b3bbb2f241e9882adbf2f22030/Form.php#L769) `isValid` method, and  check your code for errors, xdebug can be good option to do it..

Comment: As I said before, my form is not submitted. I keeping searching why....

Comment: @L.Baptiste I know, that's why I'm suggesting what you can do to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

IF you submit the form, you should have all the errors in the profiler bar(there is a form icon which you can click to see errors in the submitted form)

Comment: Hello, Profiler says : "This form was not submitted." :O ?

Comment: try rendering the whole form {{ form(form) }} and see if there is a difference

Comment: I got the same message, the form was not submitted

Comment: check  the <form> tag if it has correct action and method